# works locally perfect but not online

Tags: jquery

```
<link href="../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Styles/Site_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.vticker.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="../Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Site.js"></script>
```

JQuery not defined error, functions in Site.js are no more reached.
Can any one help please

Comment: Post your folder structure, both offline and online. Also, link to the website you are testing would be great.

Comment: also paste your javascript console message

Answer (score 1):

try to access the your paths when it is deployed online. Sometimes, relative paths can be a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but sometimes there are case sensitivity differences between the local filesystem and the web server hosting your pages.  Make sure the case of the URLs match the case of the files on your host's filesystem exactly.  For example, it's possible the file is named site.js, but when accessed locally on a case insensitive filesystem, Site.js works fine.  When hosted online, that same path may not work.